# Sync Android phone with Linux PC

Tags: android, linux, sync, calendar, address-book

How can I sync my Android mobile phone's contacts and calendar with my Linux Desktop without having a Google server as 'man in the middle'?

Comment: Will also depend on what software you are using to manage calendar and contacts in linux.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to write a Sync Adapter to synchronize your changes with your PC and other applications.

Android provides an example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I am experimenting with this just now.  It looks as if you can run an OpenSync server on Linux and connect from a Funambol client running on Android. Then use Evolution on Linux with its OpenSync adaptor. Unfortunately this is not a USB connection; it will be wireless.